# Unable to fire update and insert query in access using C# windows application

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to create one windows application with MS Access backend but I am facing some problems for insert and update query.

The select statement works fine for me, but insert and update are not working. The message is: `syntax error in "update" and " insert into "`

below is my connection string to connect access database

```
<add key="AppConnection" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=GNDb.mdb;
  Jet OLEDB:Database Password=@black123;" ></add>
```

And Queries that I am trying to fire from front end to backend

Insert : `insert into tblU(UserName, Password) values('ops1', 'ops')`

Update : `Update tblU set Password='pqr5' where UserName='pqr'`

this is my table schema:

```
ID            - AutoNumber
UserName text - text
Password      - text
```

In Front end I use Oledb connection and command.
I am using 2003 ms access mdb file. I do not know which kind of syntax error is this?
Please suggest me the correction/Answer

Comment: do you have sufficient rights on the `*.mdb` file? or read only rights?

Comment: yaa means that file was created by me and i set the password for it ie i mention in connection string

Comment: i meant this http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/setting-permissions-to-access-database-step-by-step-guide-96087.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password is a reserved word and should be enclosed in square brackets.

```
insert into tblU(UserName, [Password]) values('ops1', 'ops')
```

Reserved words in [Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) and [ACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: This depends on the version of Access. You are right for version 2007, but in 2002/ 2003 this is not the case: [List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;286335)

Comment: @JensH The OP is not using Access, they are using Jet, the database that pre-2007 versions of Access use. See my link above it is to "List of reserved words in Jet 4.0"